# Return a percentage of the full record set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query, t-sql

I'm pulling back a list of orders but I need to only display a percentage of the records.  for example we want the top 30 or top 50.  The percentagbe is variable so I'd like to not use TOP.  I tried the code below but I'm getting back no records.

```
SELECT x.SelectionCriteriaID, 
       x.DeliveryCriteriaID, 
       x.SurveyID, 
       x.intappid, 
       x.intcustomerID, 
       x.intorderid, 
       x.RowNumber RowNumber,
       x.cntoid
  FROM (SELECT @SelectionCriteriaID SelectionCriteriaID, 
               @DeliveryCriteriaID DeliveryCriteriaID, 
               @SurveyID SurveyID, 
               ord.intappid, 
               ord.intcustomerID, 
               ord.intorderid, 
               ord.cntoid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ord.intcustomerid) AS RowNumber
          FROM ord
         WHERE ord.cntoid >= ISNULL(@MinNumberOrders, 1)
           AND ord.cntoid < ISNULL(@MaxNumberOrders, 999999999))x
 GROUP BY x.SelectionCriteriaID, x.DeliveryCriteriaID, x.SurveyID, x.intappid, x.intcustomerID, x.intorderid, x.RowNumber, x.cntoid
 HAVING x.rownumber < MAX(x.RowNumber)/(100/@percent)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should be using the `TOP` clause.  This is perfectly legal (assuming you're using SQL Server):

```
declare @top_val int = 30

select top (@top_val) percent
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
from yourTable
order by <something>;
```

The above query will select the top 30% of the rows.  As far as I can tell from your question, this satisfies your requirements and is the simplest method.

Comment: ok I feel foolish.  I wasn't aware that Top could be given as a percent.  Thanks Shark

Comment: @Lumpy No need to feel foolish, the parenthesis are required with a variable.  By the way, is this SQL Server you are using?  I'm assuming that, but it's not tagged as such.

Comment: yeah sql server 2008 r2.  you had it pegged.

Comment: And really add an `ORDER BY` when you use `TOP`. Unless you don't care for which results will be returned - and you only care about the number of rows returned.

Comment: @ypercube Agreed!